# Promise All is causing a 204 response

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, es6-promise

During my page load I am trying to load two datasets.

Both of these load on a `Promise` so I have been trying to use `Promise.all`

Unfortunately when I use this technique I get a `204` for my `request.status`

Notes:

- These requests are using `XMLHttpRequest` not `fetch`
- They are plain `GET` requests
- They work fine in isolation

Here is the code as a `Promise.all`

```js
let p1 = dataLibrary.asyncStoreList();
let p2 = dataLibrary.asyncGetAllResults(2);

Promise.all([p1, p2]).then(([{stores,data}]) => {
  buildAverageByStore(stores, data);
  // ... More code
});
```

If I chain the `Promises` it works fine:

```js
let stores, data;
dataLibrary.asyncStoreList().then(s => {
  stores = s.map(store => {
    store.speed = {};
    return store;
  });
  dataLibrary.asyncGetAllResults(2).then(d => {
    data = d;
    buildAverageByStore(stores, data);
  });
});
```

Anyone else seen this behavior, am I missing something simple?

Comment: Should just be `Promise.all([p1, p2]).then(([stores,data])// no {}`. What's wrong with 204, that's a valid status?

Comment: The 204 is only occuring when I use Promise.all. I read that 204 can be a CORS preflight and tried to handle. But it did not help. When I get 204 I get no data and so a JSON error.

Comment: @charlietfl possibly a `destructuring` error on my part? changed to `[stores,data]` no more `204`. Does not make sense to me. But thx !!!

Comment: Ok, it is intermittent, still getting 204 on occassion and it returns no JSON. Just seems strange never seen this before using Promise.all

Comment: Quite honestly don't think the issue has anything to do with Promise.all. Do you control the api endpoints?

Comment: Agreed, tempted to remove question. Other that destructuring error, it does not add value.

Comment: When you get a 204 response, it’s expected that it will lack a response body (no data). That’s what 204 means.

Comment: @sideshowbarker I understand that. But why would I get this on a JSON request? Its still happening and ONLY when I use the Promise.all syntax.

Comment: No idea. As @charlietfl said I wouldn’t think it’d have anything to do with Promise.all. Regardless it seems like there’s something odd/off about the server you’re making the requests to. If you have admin access to that server, I think you’d want to go into the server code and see under what conditions it’s configured to respond with a 204 and why.

Comment: Agree with you both, there is something wrong here. Thanks for taking the time. I have now been able to reproduce the issue with the `chained promise`.

Comment: Does the real world code always use hard coded argument passed to `asyncGetAllResults(2)` or does it rely on the other request for that value?

Comment: It is actually hardcoded for this page yes (basically last two days). @charlietfl appreciate the time you have taken. But I think this is a red herring and the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Well if you are reproducing with the other version sounds like a back end issue. Or bug in one of those methods that returns the promises